# Extracting surfaceView, surfaceHolder when passed through intent

Tags: android, android-service

While creating a service as need be, surfaceView & surfaceHolder are being passed via intent to a service. How can the same be extracted at the service side.
Have been trying this but not able to succeed.
ACTIVITY :

```
intent2.putExtra("surfaceView",mSurfaceView.toString());
intent2.putExtra("surfaceHolder",mSurfaceHolder.toString());
```

SERVICE:

```
Object view_obj = intent.getExtras().get("surfaceView");
mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view_obj;
Object holder_obj=intent.getExtras().get("surfaceHolder");;
mSurfaceHolder = (SurfaceHolder) holder_obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass any `View` via an `Intent` extra. While you could implement `Parcelable` on your `SurfaceHolder` implementation, all that will do is give your service a *copy* of the `SurfaceHolder`, one that is not attached to any `SurfaceView`.

Comment: I am trying to achieve background video recording whenever my app is in focus. To do so I have been trying to pass the surfaceView and surfaceHolder to my service which i create in every Activity. So making surfaceHolder in just landing activity and saving its state while app goes background and restoring it when app comes back in focus via making it serializable or parcelable do the deed ?

Comment: @lancer025: I have no idea how to accomplish what you are trying to do, sorry.

Comment: Anyways, Thanks. your idea showed me a possible path to accomplish so.
@CommonsWare